How can I render a view result row?
I want to use an autocomplete input field for the global search on my Drupal 9 page. But instead of listing term suggestions to show what the user might search I use a custom controller and a search api view to find and display the matching result nodes as "autocomplete" results.
So in the step after getting the results from my search api view by
$view = Views::getView('search_content');
if (is_object($view)) {
  $view->setArguments($args);
  $view->setDisplay('autocomplete');
  $view->execute();
}

I want to return all these results to the JavaScript function of the tomickigrzegorz/autocomplete module. I have to place every result into my array $matches['label' and return it as a JSON object. The receiving JavaScript function will map every element and place it into a <li> element.
Until here my code works properly.
My question is: Can I render my view result rows (using the appropriate view mode defined in the view row settings) in my php controller like I can render the whole view by doing
$rendered = $view->render();
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($rendered);

I found serveral tips but could only find some for Drupal 7.

Off the top of my head, if the JS is expecting a JSON response, you need to return a JsonResponse object from the controller in Drupal back to JS formatted as a JSON object that the JS library expects to receive.

In fact, thinking about it more, the View could be a REST Export and serialized for you instead of a regular View.

The JSON response and the whole process is not my problem. I would like to render every single view result row. But I don't know if and how this is still possible from drupal 8 on.

Thanks, Kevin. REST export is a good idea for the next project. This time I built my own template rendering class and method in my custom module. So my problem is solved.

You can add a custom event to the autocomplete method in JavaScript. Maybe you can go this way. Here is an example (near line 79): https://git.drupalcode.org/project/permissions_by_term/-/blob/3.1.x-dev/js/src/drupal-behavior-function/node-form-client.js?ref_type=heads
